# Is it possible to change an encrypted volume's password w/o recreating the volume?

Tags: macos, encryption, disk-utility, logical-drive

I have a 10G encrypted volume bundle created with Disk Utility. I want to change it's encryption password. How can I do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the "Change Password..." feature from the Images menu in Disk Utility. (Under the File menu in 10.7+. Hat tip to ymasood)

Comment: On OS X Lion, I found the 'Change Password' option under the File menu and not the Images menu in the menu bar.

Comment: On OS X Mountain Lion, it is still in the File menu, but grayed out – until you open the menu while holding down the Opt key.

Comment: I still have it greyed out and holding down opt isn't doing anything. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

`hdiutil chpass` *image*

You will be prompted for the passwords.